# Overlapped CoverFlow in Flutter

Tags: flutter, carousel, coverflow

I was trying to create the old Iphone Coverflow design using flutter. I have tried listview with align widthfactor. But it overlaps only one way.

```
Container(
          height: 300,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 25,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) => Align(
              widthFactor: 0.8,
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 120,
                color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.4),
                child: Center(child: Text(position.toString())),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]
I need to achieve the design on the picture. How can I achieve this?
I have tried all available packages I think like PreloadPageview, finite coverflow, simple coverflow, perspective pageview and so on. I can achieve the transformation but not the overlapping both side and horizontal scroll at a time

Comment: Did you use any packages?

Comment: I have tried all available packages like PreloadPageview, finte coverflow, simple coverflow and so on. I can achieve the transformation but not the overlapping both side and horizontal scroll at a time

Comment: try this . this was awsome. https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider

Comment: @GHPrakash I tried this one too. All these packages are created mainly using pageview. And flutter pageview doesn't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

this is quite similar to your requirement, [perspective_pageview](https://pub.dev/packages/perspective_pageview):

```
Container(
          child: Center(
            // Adding Child Widget of Perspective PageView
            child: PerspectivePageView(
              hasShadow: true, // Enable-Disable Shadow
              shadowColor: Colors.black12, // Change Color
              aspectRatio: PVAspectRatio.ONE_ONE, // Aspect Ratio of 1:1 (Default)
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    debugPrint("Statement One");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    debugPrint("Statement Two");
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                )
              ],

            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: I tried this one too. But in pageview pages don't overlap. If the viewFraction is reduced the card size reduces while I need overlapping the reduced size

Answer (score 0):

It is not overlapped coverflow what you want exactly.

Here is my package.
https://pub.dev/packages/coverflow

I tried to implement overlapped widget... failed...

[image]

```
import 'package:coverflow/coverflow.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final List<String> titles = [
    "Title1",
    "Title2",
    "Title3",
    "Title4",
    "Title5",
    "Title6",
    "Title7",
    "Title8",
  ];

  final List<Widget> images = [
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.cyan,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.grey,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
  ];

  List<Widget> images2 = [
    Image.asset('assets/1.jpg'),
    Image.asset('assets/2.jpg'),
    Image.asset('assets/3.jpg'),
    Image.asset('assets/4.jpg'),
    Image.asset('assets/5.jpg'),
    Image.asset('assets/6.jpg'),
    Image.asset('assets/7.jpg'),
    Image.asset('assets/8.jpg'),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 200,
          child: CoverFlow(
            images: images2,
            titles: titles,
            textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I highly appreciate your hardwork. You've done really nice job. Though this is not the exact solution but the closest one. I am accepting this. Thank you

Comment: I have successfully done the overlapping. If you agree I can contribute to your pub package

Comment: Sure. No problem. Please contribute this package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After some research I have found [Overlapped Carousel Package](https://pub.dev/packages/overlapped_carousel) which seems to do exactly what you need.

Hope it will help others as well.
Happy coding

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I solved the problem after so many hard-working days. You shared my package which I built and published.

Comment: hah. Your package is wonderful and currently I am using some modules of it. Thank you